Right terminology for physical filing?
I come from an IT background (software development). Recently I have transitioned into a role which requires a lot of physical filing.
My role involves digitizing physical files, cataloguing and sorting said physical files. And indexing physical files. Due to contractual reasons, my department needs to keep and be able to present original physical files.
Is there a better term I should use then "physical" when referring to files and filing in the real physical world? "hard" filing... "paper" filing...
Also, I have built a database which tracks where physical files are stored (location, cabinet, draw, order) and I do not want to confuse any future database maintainers when they see the term "files".
Suggestions and advice would be appreciated.

"digitising and hardcopy archiving" is how I'd describe what you do.

Yes; Hardcopy vs Softcopy

@GregoryCurrie: and now how can anyone make a proper answer without repeating what you said? :) You should just write a proper answer, that is.

@virolino I didn't feel like my answer is authoritative at all because I don't work in such a field. I'm happy for people to run with it, they don't need to credit me.

To finish off the question, as answered by @Gregory Currie
"digitising and hardcopy archiving" is how I'd describe what you do.

I'd say "digitizing", but I'm in the US.

Paper files (the things you handle) and paper filing (the activity you engage in) are  common and unambiguous terms.
When needing to explicitly distinguish, you might refer to computer files.
If you were distinguishing the location of a computer file from a paper file, you might say "directory" (or "folder") versus "hardcopy location".
I assume by "digitising" paper files you mean "scanning" them - taking an photographic reproduction.
If you were transferring the data without reproducing the paper copy photographically, then that would typically be called "data entry".
